# Is it important to use baseUrl() in Zend Framework view scripts?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Some people have reported issues with accessing, setting, or getting the right value from `baseUrl()` in a view script.  But I'm wondering why it is necessary to use it at all, at least in a situation like mine where the ZF application is on a virtual private host (Amazon EC2) where I have full control of the directory structure and apache rewrite rules, as well as routes.

I know, for example, that in the filesystem `foo.jpg` lives in `public/images/foo.jpg`, and that the application's mod_rewrite will direct all requests to `public` - so in my view scripts it's a lot simpler/clearer and more efficient to write something like

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg" />
```

instead of

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/images/foo.jpg" />
```

What sort of future-proofing robustness or other benefit does the use of `baseUrl()` really provide?  So far I haven't used it at all, and had no problem.  But I've inherited some code that uses it, and my inclination is to strip out those uses whenever I'm editing a view script that contains them.  Would I regret that later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used this way, it's not really useful, but on the other hand, using it this way

```
echo $this->baseUrl('/images/foo.jpg')
```

might prove to be useful in the future since you can add logic before printing the URL. Imagine that in a few years your website grows way more than you expected and you have to move all your static content to a `Content delivery network (CDN)` you will have to manually (or with search and replace) correct all your images/css/js instances URLs. With the `baseUrl()` (or as name it `assetUrl()`) you would just have to add your CDN's url and it will be fixed everywhere in your application.

**EDIT**

I found a use for the `baseUrl()` in the code you inherited :

It would allow you to add a common URL part to all of your links and references, in the case that your site is not at the root of the domain

```
i.e. : www.mysite.com/zf-app/
```

In your config file you would just have to add

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/zf-app/"
```

for it to work, and all of your links would be prepended with that part

Comment: I think I get your point.  You mean that in future I could write my own view helper with a baseUrl() member function that would examine its parameter to determine the appropriate CDN server to use for that particular resource?  I guess that does make sense.  But the way that it appears in the code I've inherited is the way I showed in the question, just "manually" prepending the result of a call with an empty argument.  So I'll +1 this because it provides helpful insight, but defer checking it in case someone else comes up with a reason for using it as shown.

Comment: +1.  I'd always use the `baseUrl` helper just to get away from having "hardcoded" paths in your HTML.  Imagine a situation where you distribute your app to someone and they don't install it in the root directory of the site, now all content references will have to be changed to use baseUrl.  Use it now and it can save a lot of time later, and make the application more portable.

Comment: Okay, the edit points out a simple use that maybe the original code authors had in mind, though clearly the original answer shows the way the helper is intended to be used, so I've accepted the answer.  The possibility of using a CDN someday does seem more likely than installing it somewhere other than the domain's root.  So I guess that instead of stripping out the uses I find, I'll change them to the form suggested.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Perfect example. I have a couple of basic Zend-y utilities I built on separate systems. On my test platform, I just virtual host them all each with their own document root. Generally I access these tools over a remote web browser but that requires I VPN to the system running it as I didn't create these tools to be on anything more than a subnet and don't really want to expose them to an internet facing site.
So along comes android phones and things like bitweb server that allows you to run a lighttpd, php and mysql in minimalized forms on a pocket cell phone. Only problem is, it's not really set up to be powerful enough to virtual host on android operating systems.
No problem, it will allow for basic aliasing, so I just move all the tools each into their own sub-directory on my sdcard and use lighttpd mod_alias definitions to point to each and then create re-write rules for each subdirectory. But that led me to this post and others like it to fix all the static urls that pointed to href="/some/path/to/static/content"
I even had to update some urls to zend tools that were absolute paths to utilize {view}->url() calls instead.
By adding the baseUrl calls to the front of the static content, and using the view url() method for calling controller actions, I can now move the entire Zend MVC for any one of the independent tools into any directory I want and have them run from as deep in the web-tree as I desire. Zend does the rest and all it takes is 2-3 properly formatted entries in the lighttpd conf file.